# IP address 169.254.xxx.xxx if connection of a device via switch

Tags: dhcp, switch, ip-address

All:

my notebook is connected via WIFI with my router and has a valid IP-address 192.168.178.xxx. A switch (TP-LINK TL-SG1016) is connected  to the ethernet port of my notebook and another device is connected (via cable) to the switch.

The output of ipconfig shows that the IP address 169.254.xxx.xxx is associated with the ethernet port. And the device behind the switch has a different address also of the form 169.254.xxx.xxx. The command ping works to cummunicate with the device.

DHCP is activated on my router and clearly works for the WIFI connection (Notebook, smartphone,...).

Do I have to connect the switch to the router directly via LAN to get an IP address of the form 192.168.178.xxx for the device behind the switch? As I said, I connected the switch to the ethernet port of my notebook which is connected via WIFI with my router.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I have to connect the switch to the router directly via LAN to get an IP address of the form 192.168.178.xxx for the device behind the switch?

Yes. Currently, the LAN on the switch is an entirely separate network. For the router’s DHCP service to be available for devices on the switch, the switch needs to be connected to your router. A device (your laptop) that is coincidentally connected to both the switch and the router is not enough.

More complicated solutions (over Wi-Fi, with a so-called Media Bridge, which is often a Wi-Fi repeater, too) are possible but should be avoided unless it is entirely impossible to get a wired connection.

In fact, if the other device is connected to the router’s LAN, it will also be accessible over Wi-Fi, so your laptop doesn’t really need to connect to the wired network.

Comment: If I go for a Media Bridge, then the device on the switch is accessible over my smartphone (which is connected via WIFI to my router. Is that true?

Comment: If your other device successfully gets a DHCP address from the router, all devices connected to the router can directly reach it. Smartphone, laptop, whatever. Whether your other device has an all-wired connection to the router or not doesn’t matter.

Comment: My question pertains to the comment to the answer of @Spiff. He said... "...However, one downside of doing it this way is that other devices on your home Wi-Fi won't be able to see that device or talk to it very easily, because it's on the wrong side of a NAT gateway." ... and referred to the Internet Connectio Sharing option, in which case, if I am not mistaken, the device on the switch gets an DHCP address from the router.

Comment: @Simon No, that’s not how Internet Connection Sharing works. Instead, it _makes_ the PC running ICS a(/another) router. It will create a firewalled network, with a separate IP subnet and its own DHCP server. Windows ICS uses the 192.168.137.x subnet. A Media Bridge is something different, what Spiff describes in his “third thing” paragraph.

Comment: If I enable ICS on my laptop, can I access the device on the switch over my smartphone? Are they in the same network? I guess not, because you said ICS provides 192.168.137.x, while my smartphone gets 192.168.178.xxx. Is that true?

Comment: That’s correct, though the “why” is a little more nuanced (as Spiff wrote, “on the wrong side of a NAT gateway”).

Answer (score 0):

Computers can be attached to multiple networks simultaneously, but they don't automatically bridge (connect) those networks together, because it would cause traffic-routing chaos. So your Ethernet switch out the Ethernet port of your laptop is a little standalone island of a network, with nothing acting as a DHCP server to help distribute IP addresses.

It would probably be best in the long run to wire your Ethernet switch to a LAN port of your main home gateway router.

Barring that, another easy way to give Internet connectivity to that other device connected to the standalone switch would be to enable Internet [Connection] Sharing in the OS on your laptop. This causes your laptop to act as a little NAT gateway router and DHCP server, serving the standalone switch as if it's another private home LAN. However, one downside of doing it this way is that other devices on your home Wi-Fi won't be able to see that device or talk to it very easily, because it's on the wrong side of a NAT gateway.

In many cases a third thing you could do would be to tell your OS to just transparently bridge the two networks, but this is a difficult-to-configure option in your case, because Wi-Fi APs (wireless routers) by default prevent client devices like your laptop from bridging traffic from other devices; the AP would reject that traffic as coming from an unknown wireless MAC address. You'd have to find a way to make your laptop's Wi-Fi card act as what's called a "Proxy STA", or maybe set up what's called a "WDS" link between your laptop and your existing Wi-Fi AP; neither of these options are commonly supported, so you might have a lot of hassles getting this set up.

A fourth option would be to subnet your home LAN and make your laptop act as a simple IP-forwarding router (no NAT), but that also has advanced networking hassles as you'd have to tell your existing wireless router about this other subnet, and that the laptop's Wi-Fi interface's IP address is the address of the router that can get traffic to that subnet. That is, you'd have to add a manual/static route entry to your existing router's routing table. Most wireless routers don't give you the ability to edit their routing tables manually, so you might have to overcome a lot of hassles to make that work.

Comment: As for the second option (ICS): Say, ICS makes it possible that the device on the switch gets an IP address like 192.168.178.xxx. Nevertheless, I would not be able to find the device with my smartphone, which is via WIFI connectced in the same network (192.168.178.xxx)?

Comment: @Simon ICS would make the device on the switch get an IP address in a different private subnet, such as 192.168.1.xxx. But your smartphone on Wi-Fi would not be able to find it because most discovery protocols don't traverse routers. Even trying to connect by IP address would be tricky because it must be reached at the IP address of the laptop's Wi-Fi interface, AND the laptop's ICS (NAT) must be configured to have a port forwarding rule or DMZ set up so the ICS knows to forward traffic to the device.